# Why does a method with return type List<String> return a JSON but return type of String return a html?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to learning springboot. I have a simple `@Restcontroller` which has two end points `/hello` and `/helloworld`.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication

@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello")
    public String sayHelo(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/helloworld")
    public List<String> sayHelloWorld(){
        return List.of(
                "Hello","World"
        );
    }
}
```

When I go to `localhost:8080/hello` I am getting the response as a html page.[image]

But when I go to `localhost:8080/helloworld` the response is a JSON.
[image]
I do not understand why the first request I am getting as a html and the second as a JSON.
I was expecting a JSON in the first request as well.

Comment: `/hello` is actually returning `text/plain`, a reasonable choice in my view. What did you expect instead?

Comment: I expected json

Comment: What should the `json` for the `/hello` endpoint have been like?

Comment: `{"hello"}`as an object in `json` format because `/helloworld` returns a `json` response as `[{"hello"},{"world"}]`

Comment: `{"hello"}` is no valid JSON. If you know that your `String` contains valid JSON, you can of course explicitly set it: `@GetMapping(path = "/hello", produces = "application/json")`. `List<String>` on the other hand always can be serialized to valid JSON.

Comment: {
   "0": "hello"
}

I wanted the output something like this. I tried using `@GetMapping(path = "/hello", produces = "application/json")`. It shows error as: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`